# What happens if a character who is multi-classed is True Polymorphed?

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing, polymorph

The basic notion is that the rules of multi-classing in D&D 5e state that a character who chooses to multi-class must meet a stat requirement of both classes.

Now, what happens if and when the character is True Polymorphed into another creature that may have mental stats that don't meet the multi-class requirement? Especially if they no longer meet all stat requirements.

Can they still gain experience, and how do they decide where to apply it?

Typcially all characters are allowed one class even if it doesn't meet the stat requirement, but nothing covers what happens in the above eventuality.

Answer (score 8):

Doesn't matter. As by the rules of True Polymorph you loose every game statistic other than alignment and personality. You are no longer a multi-classed creature and therefor don't gain advances in these classes.

Comment: This is correct

Comment: DMG has rules on monsters/creatures gaining levels in classes. Albeit for monster building, it stands to reason that a monster can gain levels. That being said once you revert back to your "true" form you would likely lose all said levels and regain your old class and levels. One might argue that your memory is also removed since you lose Languages in favor of the new form's according to Crawford.

Comment: "One might argue that your memory is also removed since you lose Languages in favor of the new form's according to Crawford."
Eh, I'm not so sure. You retain your personality, and personality is partly a function of your experiences. This plus the fact that it specifies languages, whereas "memories" would also encompass learned languages, doesn't really leave a lot of room for that argument. (edit: lol, I originally posted this as an answer by mistake. Everyone point and laugh.)

Comment: What about using this spell to change yourself into a humanoid of another race? It's still changing from one creature essentially to another. 

(Keeping the argument of which stats would actually follow you when you 'change' races aside, what would happen if say a Rogue/Fighter Elf was suddenly and permanently shaped into a Dwarf. (The +2 Dex just happen to cover what the rogue stat requirement.)

Certainly you don't just 'forget' everything and become a mindless Dwarf?

Comment: I also have to question RAI on this, if I lost every game stat, how I could possibly remember to keep concentration on this when I transformed. Why would I remember everything if I was transformed into a cup, but lose everything if I somewhat 'permanently' TP'd into a creature and was later TP'd back into my original form.

Answer (score 5):

You can still gain levels in any class you already have at least 1 level in. The limitation is on "new" classes:

> To qualify for a **new** class, you must meet the ability score 
>   prerequisites for both your current class and your new 
>   one, as shown in the Multiclassing Prerequisites table.

Comment: RAW I fully agree. RAI, I have my doubts.